# What was the prime directive for keeping the Veil in the Department of Mysteries?

Tags: harry-potter

From the information I gathered from the H/P Wiki, it says that the veil is a barrier between the land of the living and the land of the dead.

Just wondering on this but what was the prime directive for keeping the veil? How did the Ministry of Magic come across it, and more importantly what information were the Department of Mysteries hoping to acquire since the Department of Mysteries is like the FBI and work on very top secret, undercover missions of some sorts and work of confidential nature.

Is this question answerable through in canon references? That would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Surely the department of mysteries is interested in... you know... mysterious stuff. They aren't necessarily looking for something concrete, but rather poking around hoping to make a cool discovery.

Comment: On a side note, does anyone know where on canon is it stated that the veil is a barrier between the land of living and dead? I mean, I know it is pretty easy to infer, but does anyone actually state this in the books? From what I recall, nobody is really sure what that thing is.

Comment: @Voldemort: JKR interview from 2008; quote in my answer to another Veil question here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54280/who-created-the-veil-in-the-death-chamber-and-why/54287#54287

Comment: @alexwlchan - that is the most information I think we would find on this particular topic, and I feel it answers this question too.