# Why didn't anyone investigate The Veil?

Tags: harry-potter, sirius-black

In Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, there is an important moment in which ...

> ... Sirius Black is killed.

The [book](https://goo.gl/fkFo2K) and [film](https://goo.gl/Mipv3b) handle the specific moment slightly differently:

> **Film:** Bellatrix uses killing curse, definitively killing him, then he falls back into the mysterious [veil](https://bibliobooklash.files.wordpress.com/2016/08/spoiler-warning-banner.png?w=604) and disappears.
>
>
>  **Book:** Sirius dodges Bellatrix's *red* jet of light (not killing curse, which is [green](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Killing_Curse#Nature)), he laughs and taunts her, consequently gets hit squarely in the chest by a "*second jet of light*" (killing curse?), he falls back into the veil and disappears.
>
>
>  The main difference being that, in the film, we are certain Sirius died before falling into the veil and disappearing, whereas in the book we aren't certain whether the cause of death was Bellatrix's "*second jet of light*" or the veil.

The relevant scene in the film can be watched by clicking [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mw1sTLzToHc).

The relevant scene in the books is described in the following excerpt from Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 35, *Beyond the veil*.

> Harry saw Sirius duck Bellatrix’s **jet of red light**: He was laughing at her. “Come on, you can do better than that!” he yelled, his voice echoing around the cavernous room.
>  The **second jet of light** hit him squarely on the chest.
>  The laughter had not quite died from his face, but his eyes widened in shock.
>  Harry released Neville, though he was unaware of doing so. He was jumping down the steps again, pulling out his wand, as Dumbledore turned to the dais too.
>  It seemed to take Sirius an age to fall. His body curved in a graceful arc as **he sank backward through the ragged veil** hanging from the arch. . . .
>  And Harry saw the look of mingled fear and surprise on his godfather’s wasted, once-handsome face as **he fell through the ancient doorway and disappeared behind the veil**, which fluttered for a moment as though in a high wind and then fell back into place.
>  Harry heard Bellatrix Lestrange’s triumphant scream, but knew it meant nothing — Sirius had only just fallen through the archway, he would reappear from the other side any second. . . .
>  But Sirius did not reappear.
>  <sup><sub>***- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 35***</sub></sup>

Harry believes for quite some time that Sirius will reappear from the veil, he is sure of it, until he realizes otherwise, and he goes toward the veil with an idea of rescue or retrieval in mind, but Lupin is there to stop him.

Similarly to the film adaptation, Lupin grabs hold of Harry and tries to console him and convince him that ...

> Sirius really is dead, and there is nothing that can be done

Eventually Harry comes to terms with reality and agrees, then goes ...

> ... full revenge mode on Bellatrix.

So, my question is:

**Why did nobody care to investigate further?**

Within that question are a few lead-up questions like

> **How did Lupin *know* that a) Sirius was definitely dead, and b) enough about the veil to know that "*there's nothing you can do, Harry*"/"*It's too late*"?**

Fair enough that Harry accepted the truth with Lupin there to sternly tell him so, but how did Lupin know? Why was nobody interested in investigating the possibility of rescue? We as an audience may know a lot of meta-things, but how did the relevant characters know enough to decide not to investigate the issue?

Comment: Spoiler tags are enough to warn about spoilers. You don't need a 500pixel wide banner to tell people.

Comment: @Valorum You're the boss, boss. The ways people handle spoilers on this site are, as far as I'm aware, kind of up to the discretion of the person bringing up the spoiler. I quote, " it's up to users to find their own guidelines" from a question "What is the policy for spoilers?" ([link](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/980/73512)). I thought it was very considerate to go through the effort of prefacing a spoiler warning, and would very much like it to remain.

Comment: Yeah, but there's no need to go overboard. You might also want to think about editing the question (with an axe) to get to the main point quicker.

Comment: Probably nobody ever returned after crossing the veil and ppl who'd grown up in the wizarding world (like Lupin) knew enough about it to conclude that 'yep, sirius is a goner'.

Comment: @Valorum As I said earlier, "you're the boss, boss". I did read up on rules and policies regarding spoilers before making the post, so it's not as if I broke any rules. "Overboard" seems like a subjective term, unless it's specified somewhere as a rule or policy.

Comment: @Valorum As for axing, I like to be as precise as possible and provide context so as to be absolutely clear what I'm asking about (in fear of dupes or misinterpretation). As you can see from the (currently) only answer submitted, there was confusion even with all the context, so if anything I ought to add more detail (though I personally think there is no useful detail I could add)

Comment: I'm of the opinion that brevity is at the heart of a good question. Adding a vast chunk of pointless (albeit relevant) context isn't necessary since anyone capable of answering the question will already know the context. In this case, you could probably boil it just down to a 10 word question; "**Why did *everyone* at the Battle of the Department of Mysteries assume that this character was dead?**" with a picture of Sirius behind a spoiler tag in the body of the question.

Comment: @Valorum I agree that brevity is far more attractive than ramble, I must admit I struggle with that, it's one of my gaping flaws. “It is my ambition to say in ten sentences what others say in a whole book.” 
― Friedrich Nietzsche // I wish I had the skill. I might slash as much as I can once I find a decent answer

Comment: I'm always (when writing a question) fearing two things: that people will misinterpret it/miss the point and spend a long time making a great but irrelevant answer (as is the case so far here in the answer section) and that it will be considered a dupe, because mods didn't spot the detailed difference between related questions. Thus, I elaborate, a lot. I'd rather do it once, in my question, than many by clarifying "That doesn't answer the question, here's why:" in comments to every answer.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54280/who-created-the-veil-in-the-death-chamber-and-why (reposting as the first link was to a comment on an answer, not the actual question)

Comment: @Skooba Thanks but I really think there's no need to repost links to "related" questions, considering that stackexchange has [a whole side-bar section dedicated to it](http://prntscr.com/d3faux). . . Unless it's a potential dupe that you're linking for convenience, I don't see the use.

Comment: If you post a link in the comments, it appears in the side-bar.

Comment: "Heaven forbid", "Sheesh". If I offended you I apologise, it wasn't my intent. I'm always cushioning everything with "I think" or "I don't see", which means it's my opinion, but I don't have authority and you should consult with yourself how much you value my opinion - in any case, it wasn't intended as a "Stop doing that", it was intended as "I don't really get it, how is that useful", and part of your comment actually answered it "the question I linked did not appear in the "related" side bar".

Answer (score 4):

The veil has been in the Ministry for as long as the Ministry has existed. We do not know exactly when it was created or by whom. It was in the Department of Mysteries so there were Unspeakables who were "investigating" it.

From a [2005 *Leaky Cauldron* interview:](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-tlc_mugglenet-anelli-3.htm)

> MA: Our third winner question is from Monique Padelis, who’s 15, of Surrey. How and when was the veil created?
>
> JKR: **The veil's been there as long as the Ministry of Magic has been there**, and the Ministry of Magic has been there, not as long as Hogwarts, but a long time. We’re talking hundreds of years. It's not particularly important to know exactly when, but centuries, definitely.
>
> MA: Was it used as an execution chamber or just studying?
>
> JKR: No, it's just studying. **The Department of Mysteries is all about studying.** They study the mind, the universe, death…

---

Lupin was well versed in Defense Against Dark Arts,  he was the professor in Harry's third year. He was also a member of the Order of the Phoenix which had connections to the Auror Department with Moody and Kingsley, they may have been aware of the object and it could have been brought up at one of the Order's meetings.

While Lupin may not have known *exactly* what the veil was, he knew enough to recoginze its dark magic potential. Also, remember that **they are in the middle of a battle** and trying to escape with their lives. **There was no time to explore and investigate.**

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Comment: That's because [you edited your answer](http://prntscr.com/d3exd3) after reading my comment... It's also generally not satisfactory because the first part of the relevant second half is speculation (at best), and this idea of recognising its dark magic potential is also problematic. There is nothing there to answer "How did Lupin know?". As for being in the middle of battle, they had time to stop fighting and stop Harry from running in and consoling him etc. (there was a pause). While I appreciate the urgency, the fact that they ignored the possibility of saving Sirius is whats troublesome.

Comment: It was weird that you confronted me asking "how this doesn't answer the question", eventhough you knew perfectly well that I'd made that comment before you edited it to add a whole second half that actually had some relevance to the question, retroactively (after the fact).

Comment: @Skooba Where does the "Dark Magic" come in? I read the veil as a literal portal to death (hence Harry feeling like he can hear voices just beyond it), but why would that involve dark magic?

Comment: @DavidS Something that can instantly kill you, I would call dark.

Comment: @Skooba Seems like an odd leap. A wand can instantly kill you. So can a fall off a ledge, or a car. And given that the veil is a gateway to death (note that Sirius never emerges from the other side) this attitude implies death involves dark magic as well. It just doesn't feel like the jump is justified, considering all it seems to be is a door to a place that the books essentially state is real.

Comment: @DavidS To create something for that *specific* purpose does seem dark though. Wands, ledges, and cars all have other non-lethal uses, while creating a door to death itself I would see akin to opening a portal to heaven/hell/purgatory or some other dimension. The *act* of dying or death doesn't involve dark magic, but the act of killing someone or trying to commune with dead certainly has that implication.

Answer (score 2):

Something to keep in mind is that the Order has been staking out the Department of Mysteries for the past year under Invisibility Cloaks. Later, Dumbledore seems to suggest he had knowledge of what lies behind a door in the Department that is always locked.

> 'There is a room in the Department of Mysteries,' interrupted Dumbledore, 'that is kept locked at all times. It contains a force that is at once more wonderful and more terrible than death, than human intelligence, than the forces of nature. It is also, perhaps, the most mysterious of the many subjects for study that reside there. It is the power held within that room that you possess in such quantities and which Voldemort has not at all.

So Dumbledore, and therefore presumably the rest of the Order, know the secrets of the Department of Mysteries beyond just the prophecies. That suggests the reason that no one investigated is because they all knew that the veil was a door to death itself, and Sirius was definitely dead.

Comment: Brilliant answer. There's a solid connection between Dumbledore and Sirius.

Comment: I think that Dumbledore is referring to the [Love Chamber](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Department_of_Mysteries#Love_Chamber) in that quote, seeing as he says "you [Harry] posess" but Voldemort doesn't.

Comment: Is there more quotes/info you could add to back the claim "the Order has been staking out the Dpt. of Mysteries for the past year"? That does seem convincing, given that (unlike in the film) Dumbledore was there with Lupin, Harry and company,

Answer (score 0):

Sirius had already been killed when he fell through the veil.

The veil is symbolic of the barrier between the living and the dead before Sirius and Bellatrix duel. It has imagery, in Sirius crossing to the other side in more ways than one.

But when he goes through, the Ababa Kedavra spell has been cast.

Would he have died by going through the veil without the curse? Maybe.

But Harry's urge to call him back or pull him back is like him racing to the bottom of the tower in book 6. It symbolises the madness of grief, the inability to accept what has happened etc. Forgive me, I'm not an author and can't explain it well.

Comment: Ababa Kedavra xD? Anyway, doesn't answer the question

Comment: @GhotiandChips (Nice user name btw), I think this answer hints in the right direction. Remember that the book chapters are written heavily from Harry's point of view, so while it was very obvious for everybody else that Sirius died and then fell through the vail, Harry went in denial and saw only the stepping-through-the-vail part. Reminds me of people in shock trying to search a hospital for their deceased loved ones, because "I just saw him right here, he must be here somewhere". No one would search the hospital, because the death is obvious to everybody else.

Comment: It does answer the question.

Comment: It does answer the question.

Comment: Nobody investigation because they saw Sirius killed by the Avada Kedavra curse.

Comment: Picking on spelling is really as petty as it gets. Clearly it was a typo