# Are there any known experiments the Department of Mysteries has conducted?

Tags: harry-potter

During the fifth book, the Golden Trio plus Neville, Luna, and Ginny travel to the Department of Mysteries. During that time we see a variety of interesting things (Ex. the veil, prophecies, brains). Is anything known about those or other experiments? I would prefer canon based answers. I could not find an answer on [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/) but if you can please leave a link to the article!

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30766/what-is-in-the-locked-room-in-the-department-of-mysteries

Answer (score 4):

## Yes - we know they’ve studied how certain people get magic.

Dumbledore mentions in his notes on “Babbitty Rabbitty and her Cackling Stump” that the Department of Mysteries has studied how wizards get magic, and whether Muggles can ‘acquire’ it.

> “As intensive studies in the Department of Mysteries demonstrated as far back as 1672, wizards and witches are born, not created. While the “rogue” ability to perform magic sometimes appears in those of apparent non-magical descent (though several later studies have suggested that there will have been a witch or wizard somewhere on the family tree), Muggles cannot perform magic. The best — or worst — they could hope for are random and uncontrollable effects generated by a genuine magical wand, which, as an instrument through which magic is supposed to be channeled, sometimes holds residual power, which it may discharge at odd moments — see also the notes on wandlore for “The Tale of the Three Brothers.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

Comment: Typo in the last line – "sec" should be "see". Too small of an edit for me to suggest.

Comment: @Alex That’s how it’s written in the book I have, I left it exactly as written.

Comment: Is that a mistake in the book? "sec" is not a word, and the version I'm looking at has "see".

Comment: @Alex Yes, it’s possible. Mine definitely has “sec” but it may be an error in the book itself.

Comment: Nice answer! I was under the impression that that was just a Death Eater excuse for why they were interrogating Muggle-borns, but your answer corrected that misconception. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to Luna Lovegood in *Order of the Phoenix*:

> And of course he uses the Department of Mysteries to  develop terrible
>   poisons, which he feeds secretly to  anybody who disagrees with him.

According to Ron in *Order of the Phoenix*, no one really knows:

> “I know they call the people who work in there  ‘Unspeakables,’ ” said
>   Ron, frowning. “Because no one  really seems to know what they do in
>   there... Weird  place to have a weapon ...”

Ron's view is confirmed by his father at the Quidditch World Cup:

> “That was Cuthbert Mockridge, Head of the Goblin  Liaison Office. ...
>   Here comes Gilbert Wimple; he’s  with the Committee on Experimental
>   Charms; he’s  had those horns for awhile now. ... Hello, Arnie ... 
>   Arnold Peasegood, he’s an Obliviator — member of the  Accidental Magic
>   Reversal Squad, you know. ... and  that’s Bode and Croaker ... they’re
>   Unspeakables. ...”
>
> “They’re what?”
>
> “From the Department of Mysteries, top secret, no  idea what they get
>   up to. ...”

At the end of *Order of the Phoenix* Dumbledore tells us one of the most mysterious things studied there:

> “There is a room in the Department of Mysteries,”  interrupted
>   Dumbledore, “that is kept locked at all  times. It contains a force
>   that is at once more  wonderful and more terrible than death, than
>   human  intelligence, than forces of nature. It is also, perhaps,  the
>   most mysterious of the many subjects for study  that reside there. It
>   is the power held within that  room that you possess in such
>   quantities and which  Voldemort has not at all. That power took you to
>   save  Sirius tonight. That power also saved you from  possession by
>   Voldemort, because he could not bear  to reside in a body so full of
>   the force he detests. In  the end, it mattered not that you could not
>   close your  mind. It was your heart that saved you.”

In *Deathly Hallows* they apparently studied how people obtain magic, but given the circumstances the study might not have been pure:

> “ ‘Recent research undertaken by the Department of  Mysteries reveals
>   that magic can only be passed from  person to person when Wizards
>   reproduce. Where no  proven Wizarding ancestry exists, therefore, the
>   so-  called Muggle-born is likely to have obtained magical  power by
>   theft or force.

Comment: Considering JKR has stated that magic is innate, part of a person’s DNA, I’d say that “recent research” is quite indubitably not pure or worth the paper your average Rita Skeeter article is printed on.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Maybe she had access to even more recent research.